# Select Longest String - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a need to select the longest string in a SQL Server Query.

I need, the longest description from LongDescription_c when there is something in it or the longest from PartDescription.

At the moment, we have the following query created by a colleague a long time ago:

```
SELECT        PartNum, 
              MAX(CASE WHEN LongDescription_c = '' THEN PartDescription ELSE LongDescription_c END) AS PartDesc
FROM            
              Part
GROUP BY 
              PartNum
```

This works in a lot of circumstances but not all and I believe the reason for this is the `MAX()`. As i believe this returns in alphabetical order rather then `MAX(LEN())` which is what I believe he wanted. However, I cannot work out how to use `MAX(LEN())` as this will purely return the maximum length as an integer.

Thanks for any help in advance as Im a bit stuck at this point.

Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry I should have said this is one step in quite a large query so the performance using that is quite bad

Comment: @DaRoGa If you really need the max then SQL Server has to consider every record; there is no getting around this, even if you use an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would requited to use `len()` function in order to check length of string

```
select top(1) with ties PartNum, * 
from table t
order by row_number() over (partition by PartNum order by 
                       len(CASE WHEN LongDescription_c = '' 
                                THEN PartDescription ELSE LongDescription_c END) desc)
```

Comment: Accepting this answer as this gave me the solution and the performance required. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Along the lines of what @jarlh was saying, one option would be to use a `TOP` trick:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Part
ORDER BY
    LEN(CASE WHEN LongDescription_c = ''
             THEN PartDescription ELSE LongDescription_c END) DESC,
    CASE WHEN LongDescription_c = ''
             THEN PartDescription ELSE LongDescription_c END
```

In the case of a tie, it would report the alphabetically lowest description first.

If performance be an issue, then adding an index is the typical thing to do.  But in this case, because we are ordering using a function, the index cannot be used.  If you really need performance, then consider adding a computed column to store the length.

Answer (score 2):

Following query will give you row with longest `LongDescription_c`

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Part]
ORDER BY LEN(LongDescription_c) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your colleagues query is wrong.

If your LongDescription_c is always longer than PartDescription column, and only need to display PartDescription when LongDescription is not available, you can use a much simpler query

```
SELECT PartNum, IIF(LEN(LongDescription_c)>=LEN(PartDescription),LongDescription_c,PartDescription)
FROM Part
```

Comment: This still potentially requires calling `LEN` for each record in the table (twice, according to your version).